# Why are the dimensions of my .nc file not being recognised in R?

Tags: r, netcdf

I want to add a variable to an existing .nc file in R.

The file's Variables look like this when I input: `print.nc(open.nc("tasmax_EUR-44_mon_200601-201012.nc"))`

[image]

First, I read the data from the file:

```
nc<-nc_open("tasmax_EUR-44_mon_200601-201012.nc")
tmax<-ncvar_get(nc)
```

Then I tried to create the variable that I will use with `ncvar_add`

```
ncvar_def("tasmax","K",list(rlon, rlat, time))
```

This returns:

```
Error in ncvar_def("tasmax", "K", list(rlon, rlat, time)) : 
  object 'rlon' not found
```

But I can see these dimensions when I inspect the file (highlighted in the attached image). Why are the dimensions not being recognised?

Doing this:

```
ncvar_def("tasmax","K",list("rlon", "rlat", "time"))
```

Returns this error:

```
[1] "Error, passed variable has a dim that is NOT of class ncdim4!"
[1] "Error occurred when processing dim number 1 of variable tasmax"
Error in ncvar_def("tasmax", "K", list("rlon", "rlat", "time")) : 
  This dim has class: character
```

Comment: should your code not be `ncvar_def("tasmax","K",list("rlon", "rlat", "time"))`. Most likely r is looking for an object called rlon, but based on your code it does not exist.

Comment: @RobertWilson I have edited my post to illustrate what happens when I include your suggestion.

Comment: This looks like an instructive error message. Please investigate what it means before asking others to figure it out for you, which goes against the spirit of SO

Comment: @RobertWilson Are you referring to the error from my actual question? Or my response to your suggestion?

Comment: The error `object 'rlon' not found` is self-explanatory: you use `list(rlon,...)` but `ncvar_def` cannot find it via the default R search path. The [docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ncdf4/ncdf4.pdf) would seem to define your `rlon` here with `rlon <- ncdim_def(...)`.